# `${}` в javascript

Tags: javascript

Как работает и для чего используется такая конструкция в js?

```js
var a = 550;
console.log(`${a}`); // выведет "550"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Не только мне лучше `'Моя переменная ' + myVariable` чем \``Моя переменная ${myVariable}`\`? Мне тут один  пользователь писал что второй вариант намного лучше, и что через + не нужно вообще делать, но как по мне, то так лучше смотрится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ES6 можно вставлять выражения при помощи **${…}**

Пример

```
let doubleNum = 2;
let tripleNum = 3;

alert(`${doubleNum} + ${tripleNum} = ${doubleNum + tripleNum}`); // 2 + 3 = 5
```

Как видно, при помощи **${…}** можно вставлять как и значение переменной `${doubleNum}`, так и более сложные выражения, которые могут включать в себя операторы, вызовы функций и т.п. Такую вставку называют **«интерполяцией»**.

Также есть

[**Вложенная интерполяция**](http://jsraccoon.ru/es6-interpolation)

Answer (score 1):

Проще понять на примере

```
var a = 550;
console.log(`Данная книга стоит ${a} рублей`);
// выведет "Данная книга стоит 550 рублей"
```

Comment: Разве у автора не такой же пример?))

Comment: @entithat нет не такой же

Answer (score 0):

```
const celsiusToFahrenheit = (c) => {
    return`${c} degrees celsius is equal to ${ c * 9 / 5 + 32 } degrees fahrenheit`;
};

celsiusToFahrenheit(1); // "1 degrees celsius is equal to 33.8 degrees fahrenheit"
celsiusToFahrenheit(5); // "5 degrees celsius is equal to 41 degrees fahrenheit"
```